# How do I return to the top of a switch statement if the input goes to default?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I was doing my homework (Generate Roman Numerals from numerical input from 1-10), and in doing so, I made a switch statement. My question is how do I return to the top of a switch statement if none of the input is selected in a case? There was nothing about it in our textbook nor could I find anything in the java documentation. Is this just something that cannot happen?

Comment: Yes, it's something that can't happen. It tests the values *once* (unless you put it in a loop), then moves on to whatever code is after the `switch` statement.

Comment: what do you mean with "top of a switch"? do you mean `case 1:` ?

Comment: Why do you want to test your data again with the same data and the same conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `break` from in case or can write `return` statement if it is method.

```
public int method(int i){
    int j=0;
    switch(i){
        case 1: ... return j;
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer the while loop to do this:

just to explain the basic idea: you initialize a boolean that will be the criteria whether the loop has to be repeated, you start the while loop and put the boolean at false because in most cases you only want to run it once, you start the switch and for all cases where you want to repeat the loop you put the boolean again equal to true.

```
boolean again= true;
while (again){
again= false;

switch(number){
case 1:
break;
case 2:
break;
default: again=true;
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it but I highly recommend you to restructure your code to avoid doing it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        loop: for (;;) {
            switch (i) {
                case 1: System.out.println(i);
                    break loop;
                case 2: // more stuff
                    break loop;
                default:
                    System.out.println(i);
                    i = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=3;
            switch (i) {       
            default:
            i=1;
            case 1: 
              System.out.println(i);
              break;
            case 2: 
              break;     
            }
    }
}
```